# (Geo)JSON to object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

I´m a beginner in JavaScript and I´m struggling a bit with converting a GeoJSON to a javascript Object Array.

So with JSON.parse I parse my serverside generated JSON into a JSON-Object. So far so good.

The Google method addGeoJson returns me [object (Array)]. But this method shows me onload the shape on the map. I need it later, when I want to display different granularities when I zoom in or out.

I need to generate an [object (Array)] out of an [object]. How do I do this? Out of "generatedGeoJsonPlz2"

This is what I have so far:

```
var generatedGeoJsonPlz1 = JSON.parse(geoJsonString); 
var generatedGeoJsonPlz2 = JSON.parse(geoJsonString2);

var plz1area = plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz1); // returns [object (Array)]

plz.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom = plz.getZoom();
  if (zoom == 8) {
    for (var i = 0; i < plz1area.length; i++) {
      plz.data.remove(plz1area[i]);
    }
    plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz2);
  }
  // here i´m struggling. i need the [object (Array)] to delete the old Json
  else if (zoom == 5) {
    var plz2area = generatedGeoJsonPlz2;

    for (var i = 0; i < plz2area.length; i++) {
      plz.data.remove(plz2area[i]);
    }
    plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz1);
  }
}
```

Thanks!
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of `addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz2)` to be able to remove it later.

This may work for you:

```js
var generatedGeoJsonPlz1 = JSON.parse(geoJsonString); 
var generatedGeoJsonPlz2 = JSON.parse(geoJsonString2);

var plz1area = plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz1);
// Here I already define the variable plz2area
var plz2area;

plz.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom = plz.getZoom();
  if (zoom == 8) {
    for (var i = 0; i < plz1area.length; i++) {
      plz.data.remove(plz1area[i]);
    }
    plz2area = plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz2);
  } else if (zoom == 5) {
    // Only remove plz2area from the map, if it has been initialized before
    if (plz2area) {
      for (var i = 0; i < plz2area.length; i++) {
        plz.data.remove(plz2area[i]);
      }
    }
    plz.data.addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I´ll try it out! Thank you so far

Comment: unfortunatly its not working. plz2area is undefined in the function so it won´t pass the forloop for deleting

Comment: Yes, in the `else if (zoom == 5)` section the for loop is only started when `plz2area` is defined. Otherwise this won't work. Or can you clarify what you mean please?

Comment: yes. But i don´t get it. When/ how do i get plz2area defined? I think i struggle with the point to  store the result of addGeoJson(generatedGeoJsonPlz2). How can i store it without getting it loaded before? My approach is to store plz2 area in a [object (Array)] and call it than in 'else if (zoom == 5)' with addGeoJson. Sorry for asking that stupid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126332/discussion-between-christi-hahnchen-and-mrunde).